# How to create multiple complex sqlite transactions with an expected out using apsw?

Tags: python, sqlite, transactions, apsw

I want to execute several complex statements in a transaction with a select statement at the end which I use for further processing.

Doing so once works fine but as soon as I execute the same statement again it causes the error below.

Test code:

```
import apsw
connection = apsw.Connection("temp.db")

cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute("""
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
CREATE TABLE Foo(x);
COMMIT;
""")

cursor = connection.cursor()
print(cursor.execute("""
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
INSERT INTO Foo (x) VALUES (1);
INSERT INTO Foo (x) VALUES (2);
SELECT x FROM Foo LIMIT 1;
COMMIT;
""").fetchone())


cursor = connection.cursor()
print(cursor.execute("""
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
INSERT INTO Foo (x) VALUES (3);
INSERT INTO Foo (x) VALUES (4);
SELECT x FROM Foo LIMIT 1;
COMMIT;
""").fetchone())
```

Output:

```
$ python test.py 
(1,)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 28, in <module>
    """).fetchone())
  File "src/cursor.c", line 236, in resetcursor
apsw.SQLError: SQLError: cannot start a transaction within a transaction
```

Edit: It seems to be connected to the "fetchone()" method, if I instead use "fetchall()" it works. In my specific case I do expect on one result, so I have edited the code to reflect this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python sqlite "BEGIN TRANSACTION" and "COMMIT" commands](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26770719/python-sqlite-begin-transaction-and-commit-commands)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQLite computes results on the fly. When you call `fetchone()`, the execution runs only as far as needed to return one row.

To ensure that all statements are executed, call `fetchall()`, or iterate over the results, even if you know that there is only one.

It might be a better idea to not squeeze as many statements as possible into a single SQL string.

Comment: Thank you for the helpful answer, I guess I will have to use `fetchall()` as I need to squeeze all statements into one transaction to ensure the correct state.

Comment: You don't need to use a single `execute` for a single transaction.